# Что делает выражение вида "handle<value>"

Tags: c++

Что делает в C++ выражение вида `handle<value>`?

В контексте `require` такие скобки понятны, а что они значат тут не совсем понимаю.

В принципе понимаю `js` и немного  `asm`, так что можно объяснить на аналоге.

**P.S.**: я уже начал читать книжку "ООП в С++" Лафоре Р., но много кода который смотрю на том-же гите содержит такие операторы, и из-за них не совсем понимаю что делает код.

Comment: А кто Вам сказал, что это операторы ? Темплейты.

Comment: ну я только начал изучать С++, так что пока не все нюансы понимаю.

Comment: Сказать по правде, есть вероятность, что Вам сейчас минусов накидают. Ибо это не столь специфичные вещи, чтобы информацию о них было сложно загуглить и понять (в общих чертах). [link](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8B_C%2B%2B)

Comment: ну а как гуглить если не совсем понимаешь что гуглить?, пробовал гуглить 'C++' и в разных комбинациях '<>', 'object<val>' и т.д. , сложно загуглить когда незнаешь как правильно составить запрос. А если минусов боятся, то зачем здесь вообще региться, да и минусы здесь это в основном троллинг, уже даже статья на эту тему на хабре проскакивала.

Comment: @vnn198 Поищите "шаблоны C++". Вкратце - вы можете написать функцию `min(int,int)` - для двух целых, такую же для двух `double`, даже для двух строк - словом, для всего, что можно сравнивать. А можно написать одну, в которой переменным параметром выступает сам **тип**. Это и есть шаблон функции. Есть шаблоны классов и т.д., но это уже детали.

Comment: ps: я давно почитывал Си, но я непомню там таких штук, мне нужно С++ потому что то с чем я хочу поработать всё на С++ написано, так что  хочешь не хочешь а часть со взаимодействием придётся писать на плюсах

Comment: Приведите контекст использования, чтобы можно было не в Вангу играть, а по делу ответить.

Comment: Ниже дал ссылку, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19231174/emitting-an-event-in-node-js-c-addon , просто иногда встречается в коде такое, и  т.к. поиск не помог ,а понять что это такое очень хотелось, пришлось спросить тут. Контекстов написания видел много разных, привёл пример который встретил сегодня.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не зная что такое `handle` и `value` сложно ответить на ваш вопрос. Попробую угадать, что речь идет о шаблонах.

Не будем погружаться в темный мир метапрограммирования, посмотрим только на вершину айсберга. Вот простой пример использования шаблона:

```
template<class T>
T summ(const T &x, const T &y){
    return x + y;
}
```

Если в коде вызвать функцию таким образом:

```
double x = 1;
double y = 2;
double z = summ(x, y);
```

Компилятор увидит что в качестве `T` следует использовать `double` и создат функцию `double summ(const double &x, const double &y)`.

К сожалению компилятор не всегда может понять какой же тип следует использовать. В таких случаях ему нужно помочь. Для этого используется алмазный синтаксис(diamond syntax). Вот например:

```
template<class T>
class MyClass{
T _variable;
//...
};

MyClass<int> myObject; //алмазный синтаксис
```

Если вернуться к нашему первому примеру, то там тоже можно так написать:

```
double x = 1;
double y = 2;
int z = summ<int>(x, y);
```

Еще раз повторяю, подстановка типа на этапе компиляции это самое простое и поверхностное применение шаблонов. Тот же Александреску в своей книге такое с ними вытворяет, что страшно становится.

Comment: Один из примеров кода тут где я столкнулся с таким написанием тут  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19231174/emitting-an-event-in-node-js-c-addon

Comment: @vnn198, там шаблонный класс. У меня в ответе `MyClass` объявлен таким же способом

Answer (score 2):

В Си++, выражение вида `Шаблон<Параметер 1,Праметер 2, .., Параметер N>` означает инстанцирование шаблона с именем "Шаблон" параметрами "Параметер 1", "Параметер 2" и так далее до "Параметер N". Инстанцирование это термин из Си++, он означает продстановку параметров в указаный шаблон, что близко по аналогии с вызовом функции с параметрами. То, что получается в результате подстановки зависит от вида шаблона: шаблон функции порождает функции, шаблон типа (или класса) порождает новые типы. Полученные сущности можно использовать так же как и обычные нешаблонные. Инстанцирование выполняет компилятор после препроцессора, то есть во время работы программы никаких шаблонов не существует они все развернуты в конкретные сущности.

[Подробнее о шаблонах Си++](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8B_C%2B%2B)